# need help finding the weighted average

Tags: python-3.2, weighted-average

getting the error in my code
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Daniel Nase/Desktop/assignment 7 test.py", line 119, in 
    main()
  File "C:/Users/Daniel Nase/Desktop/assignment 7 test.py", line 23, in main
    calculate_weighted_average(score_ammount,scores_t, score_weight, average1, num_t)
  File "C:/Users/Daniel Nase/Desktop/assignment 7 test.py", line 112, in calculate_weighted_average
    weighted_average_t = float(sum(average1))*float((score_weight.pop(0))/100)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'

I'm trying to calculated the weighted average but i don't know what I'm doing wrong...
help please!!!!

```
def main():
     score_type = ["tests","assignments","quizzes","labs"]
     score_ammount = [0,0,0,0]
     score_weight = [0,0,0,0]
     final_weight = 0

     scores_t = [0]
     scores_a = [0]
     scores_q = [0]

     total = 0
     average1 = [0]
     average2 = [0]
     average3 = [0]

     num_t = 0




     get_initial_input(score_type,score_ammount,score_weight)
     get_scores(score_ammount,average1,average2,average3,total,scores_t,scores_a,scores_q)
     calculate_weighted_average(score_ammount,scores_t, score_weight, average1, num_t)



def get_initial_input(score_type,score_ammount,score_weight):
    for x in range(0,4):
        score_ammount[x] = input("How many " + score_type[x] + " are there?")

    if input("Is there a final with a serperate weight?(1 = yes/0 = no) ") == '1':
        final_weight = int(input("What is the weight of the final?(0-100) "))
    else:
        final_weight = ""

    total_weight = 0
    while total_weight != 100:
        total_weight = 0
        print("")
        print("Please make sure the weight of all scores add up to 100")
        for x in range(0,3):
            score_weight[x] = input("What is the weight of all the " + score_type[x])
            total_weight = total_weight + int(score_weight[x])
    return score_ammount, score_weight, final_weight


def get_scores(score_ammount,average1,average2,average3,total,scores_t,scores_a,scores_q):

    num_t = int(score_ammount.pop(0))
    print("")

    for i in range(0,num_t):
        scores_t.append(0)

    for i in range(0, num_t):
        y = i + 1
        scores_t[i] = int(input("Please input test score #" + str(y) + " "))

    print(" ")

    for i in range(0,1):
        total = total + sum(scores_t)
    average1 = total/num_t
    print(int(average1))


###########################################################################

    num_a = int(score_ammount.pop(0))
    print("")

    for i in range(0,num_a):
        scores_a.append(0)

    for i in range(0, num_a):
        y = i + 1
        scores_a[i] = int(input("Please input assignment score #" + str(y) + " "))

    print(" ")
    total = 0
    for i in range(0,1):
        total = total + sum(scores_a)
    average2 = total/num_a
    print(int(average2))

###########################################################################

    num_q = int(score_ammount.pop(0))
    print(" ")

    for i in range(0,num_q):
        scores_q.append(0)

    for i in range(0, num_q):
        y = i + 1
        scores_q[i] = int(input("Please input quiz score #" + str(y) + " "))

    print(" ")
    total = 0
    for i in range(0,1):
        total = total + sum(scores_q)
    average3 = 0 + total/num_q
    print(int(average3))

    return average1, average2, average3, total, scores_t, scores_a, scores_q, num_t, num_a, num_q

def calculate_weighted_average(score_ammount, scores_t, score_weight, average1, num_t):
    num_t = int(score_ammount.pop(0))
    for i in range (0,num_t):
        average1[i] = sum(scores_t)/num_t

        weighted_average_t = float(sum(average1))*float((score_weight.pop(0))/100)
        print(weighted_average_t)





main()
```

Comment: What do you think the error message `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'` could mean?  What do you think it's telling you that you're trying to do?

Comment: That I'm trying to multiply a str and int but i don't know what do do in order to have the ammount1 be and int that i can use in order to get the weighted average

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not that you're trying to multiply a string and an int, but that you're trying to divide them (the error message says `/`, not `*`).  You can easily convert the string to an `int` or a `float`, though, like you did in these lines:

```
final_weight = int(input("What is the weight of the final?(0-100) "))

scores_t[i] = int(input("Please input test score #" + str(y) + " "))

scores_a[i] = int(input("Please input assignment score #" + str(y) + " "))

scores_q[i] = int(input("Please input quiz score #" + str(y) + " "))
```

`input` always returns a string, and if you want to get a number out of it, you have to convert it.  You didn't do that here:

```
score_ammount[x] = input("How many " + score_type[x] + " are there?")
```

and here

```
        score_weight[x] = input("What is the weight of all the " + score_type[x])
        total_weight = total_weight + int(score_weight[x])
```

you converted the value of `score_weight[x]` to an integer before adding it to `total_weight`, but `score_weight[x]` itself is still a string.